# Turtlebot obstacles

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to make my turtlebot navigate (by itself) through a room (where i give him the destination). The current solution builds a map using gmapping and then I use rviz to give it a destination on the map.

It works but now i would like to add sticky notes (of different colors) on obstacles.

Turtlebot has to detect the sticky note (from point cloud) and move itself in the right direction (based on color. For example if the sticky note is red it should go to the right, if it is green it should go to the left).

Which packages can we use? Any recommendations?

I'm a beginner with ROS and I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33380/turtlebot-obstacles/) by [ZeroCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/2321/zerocool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-05-06**:
do you need to navigate by color or would some other form of identifier be okay? like http://ros.org/wiki/ar_pose

**Comment by [ZeroCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/2321/zerocool/) on 2012-05-06**:
We need to navigate by color.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-05-07**:
I suggest you to go with the ar_pose as indicated by mwise_wg. Doing it with color may have many distortions because of the environment and it must be ideal environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[OpenCV](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vision_opencv) would be a worthy tool for this job. It packages a lot of image processing algorithms into one library and supports a wide variety of cameras. I haven't personally used it with ROS but my experience on other projects has been good.

---

Originally posted by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) with karma: 328 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3